# How to modify RectTransform properties in script [Unity 4.6 beta]

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Hello, I'm using the new UI system from Unity 4.6 beta...

Tried different codes, looked at the docs and searched around but can't find the answer…

For example. I have an image and I want to change width and height during runtime.

```
public GameObject image4;
image4.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.Set(0,0,100, 300);
```

which doesn't work. And image4.GetComponent().rect.y is GET only so cannot be changed at runtime.

I've also tried:

```
image4.transform.localScale.y = 15;
```

which doesn't work either.

what is the proper way to change size at runtime? You can give me an example in either JS or C#, doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't know why setters doesn't work as expected, but you can do this: image4.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = new Vector3(1,15,1);

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One day researching.
I found an extension that can help us to deal with new UI system.
u can improve this extension if you want.

```
public static class RectTransformExtensions
{
    public static void SetDefaultScale(this RectTransform trans) {
        trans.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }
    public static void SetPivotAndAnchors(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 aVec) {
        trans.pivot = aVec;
        trans.anchorMin = aVec;
        trans.anchorMax = aVec;
    }

    public static Vector2 GetSize(this RectTransform trans) {
        return trans.rect.size;
    }
    public static float GetWidth(this RectTransform trans) {
        return trans.rect.width;
    }
    public static float GetHeight(this RectTransform trans) {
        return trans.rect.height;
    }

    public static void SetPositionOfPivot(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 newPos) {
        trans.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, trans.localPosition.z);
    }

    public static void SetLeftBottomPosition(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 newPos) {
        trans.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x + (trans.pivot.x * trans.rect.width), newPos.y + (trans.pivot.y * trans.rect.height), trans.localPosition.z);
    }
    public static void SetLeftTopPosition(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 newPos) {
        trans.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x + (trans.pivot.x * trans.rect.width), newPos.y - ((1f - trans.pivot.y) * trans.rect.height), trans.localPosition.z);
    }
    public static void SetRightBottomPosition(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 newPos) {
        trans.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x - ((1f - trans.pivot.x) * trans.rect.width), newPos.y + (trans.pivot.y * trans.rect.height), trans.localPosition.z);
    }
    public static void SetRightTopPosition(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 newPos) {
        trans.localPosition = new Vector3(newPos.x - ((1f - trans.pivot.x) * trans.rect.width), newPos.y - ((1f - trans.pivot.y) * trans.rect.height), trans.localPosition.z);
    }

    public static void SetSize(this RectTransform trans, Vector2 newSize) {
        Vector2 oldSize = trans.rect.size;
        Vector2 deltaSize = newSize - oldSize;
        trans.offsetMin = trans.offsetMin - new Vector2(deltaSize.x * trans.pivot.x, deltaSize.y * trans.pivot.y);
        trans.offsetMax = trans.offsetMax + new Vector2(deltaSize.x * (1f - trans.pivot.x), deltaSize.y * (1f - trans.pivot.y));
    }
    public static void SetWidth(this RectTransform trans, float newSize) {
        SetSize(trans, new Vector2(newSize, trans.rect.size.y));
    }
    public static void SetHeight(this RectTransform trans, float newSize) {
        SetSize(trans, new Vector2(trans.rect.size.x, newSize));
    }
}
```

The source code I found from here:
[http://orbcreation.com](http://orbcreation.com/orbcreation/page.orb?1099)

Answer (score 8):

Hey Friend Just Try This To Change Position and Width of an UI gameObject

if you want to use instance of an object
use This 

`leftButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-125, -36f);
rightButton.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(x, y);`

And if want to put script on a UI object then try this to change height and width

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-125, -36f);
GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(x, y)
```

Comment: I can't see your answer adding any additional value to the answers already given.

Comment: just tell me what you want to know?? just tell me if Nothing then welcome and bye

Answer (score 3):

When changing parent (eg after Instantiate), things get messy, I found resetting a few parameters really helped (spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out):

```
this.transform.SetParent(content.transform);
this.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;            
this.rectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;
this.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
```

Hope that helps someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use something like that [in C#]:

```
 ...

    RectTransform rTrans = (RectTransform) transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

    // set new width and height

    rTrans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(15, 200);

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't want to modify directly those values, even more if they come from a prefab you have already setup with the correct coords, if you just want to add it correctly under canvas (or other) but it "changes position" do this:

```
GameObject instance;

void Start () {
    GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find ("Canvas");
    if (canvas != null) {
        GameObject go = Resources.Load<GameObject>("MyPrefab");
        if(go != null){
            instance = Instantiate(go);
            instance.GetComponent<Transform>().SetParent(canvas.GetComponent<Transform>(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

Passing `false` on set parent will avoid the rect transform being changed in weird forms when instantiating the prefab.

Answer (score 1):

Actuallly playing with following can help:
GetComponent.sizeDelta = new Vector(new_size.x,new_size.y);

I successfully achieved Zooming in new GUI by setting this property.

Here is my own code for scaling:

```
    void Start()
{
    // Store initial Size and Position;
    ZoomedOutSize = new Vector2(GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width, GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height);
    ZoomedOutPos = new Vector2(GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.x, GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.y);
}

void Update()
{
    // Calculate the total delta at runtime cause it depends on parent (yah i know it's not optimal to have new vector ecery Update)
    ZoomSizeRate = new Vector2(gameObject.GetComponentInParent<ZoomDialog>().MaxSize.x - ZoomedOutSize.x, gameObject.GetComponentInParent<ZoomDialog>().MaxSize.y - ZoomedOutSize.y);
    ZoomPosRate = -GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition;

    // Zoom is the float with range(0,1) 0 - no Zoom, 1 - Fully Zoom to ParentSize;
    //Set the size delta and position as Initial + Rate * Zoom
    GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(ZoomedOutSize.x + ZoomSizeRate.x * Zoom, ZoomedOutSize.y + ZoomSizeRate.y * Zoom);
    GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector2(ZoomedOutPos.x + ZoomPosRate.x * Zoom, ZoomedOutPos.y + ZoomPosRate.y * Zoom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetComponent().anchoredPosition3D;
It should work fine x , y , z are PosX , PosY and PosZ of recttransform
you can use Vector3 to store the value

```
Vector3 values = new Vector3();
public GameObject rect_obj;
//Use this if script is on that recttransform component
values = this.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D;
 //else           
values = rect_obj.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D;
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public GameObject rectPlayerCardCollection;
public GameObject rectCardInfo;

rectPlayerCardCollection.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(656f, 0, 0);
        RectTransform rt = rectPlayerCardCollection.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(669.3f, 1125.3f);
        rectCardInfo.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(-652f, 0, 0);
        RectTransform rt2 = rectCardInfo.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rt2.sizeDelta = new Vector2(626.9f, 1080f);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.